# How do I fix grayed out live tiles?

Tags: windows-10, live-tiles

My Windows 10 live tiles are all grayed out.  If I click on any of them it says to wait a few minutes and try again as they're being updated.  They've been like this for a couple weeks now.  I've run the Windows App Store repair tool and it found/fixed a corrupt cache, but the problem remains.  What else should I investigate?

Comment: Personally, I would try to [Reinstall and Re-Register All Windows Apps for All Accounts](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3175-reinstall-re-register-apps-windows-10-a.html).  Under similar circumstances, that has worked for me in the past.

Comment: That did the trick!  Make it an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *My Windows 10 live tiles are all grayed out. If I click on any of them
>   it says to wait a few minutes and try again as they're being updated.*

You can utilize PowerShell to reinstall all of the built-in Windows apps for all accounts. Under similar circumstances, that has consistently worked for me in the past. Use the following procedures:

> 1. Press <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
> 2. Type **PowerShell** within the search field
> 3. Right-click the result titled **Windows PowerShell** and choose **Run as Administrator**
> 4. Acknowledge the subsequent UAC prompt, as necessary
> 5. Copy-and-paste the following command into the PowerShell window and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:
>
>    ```
>    Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
>    ```
> 6. Watch the reinstall processes scroll by and wait for them to finish:
>
>    [image: PowerShell]
> 7. Reboot and verify the functionality of the built-in Windows apps

(Source: [Reinstall and Re-register Apps in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3175-reinstall-re-register-apps-windows-10-a.html))