# Reinstall Universal Windows Platform

Tags: windows-10, uwp

My Universal Windows Platform is completely broken on one of my systems, all UWP apps are greyed-out and display an exclamation mark on them including the store. None of the apps run. Some display the error "This app can't open" while the store doesn't display anything, it simply doesn't run. Resetting apps deletes them. I now don't have the store on my system as a result. I wish to repair this without having to reinstall my operating system. Is it even possible, if so, how?

Comment: Did you already try to [utilize the PowerShell method](https://superuser.com/questions/1299967/how-do-i-fix-grayed-out-live-tiles/1300193#1300193) to reinstall them?

Comment: There is nothing to reinstall, UWP support, exisst at the kernel level.  You either have to determine what actions you performed to cause this behavior or reinstall the OS.

Answer (score -1):

Run the Windows App Troubleshooter. Type the troubleshoot in Search Box ->Windows Store Apps

Try to run DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth command in Command Prompt (as admin).

Here are links about reinstall store.

How To Reinstall Store And Other Preinstalled Apps In Windows 10 :
http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-reinstall-store-and-other-preinstalled-apps-in-windows-10/

Re-register And reinstall windows 10 store Apps To fix Freezes and Crashes problem
https://howtofixwindows.com/reinstall-windows-10-store-modern-apps/